# Approximate confidence interval; Rayleigh Distribution

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval

This is a HW problem in my undergrad Statistics course. I am unsure of how to proceed. We were given a text file of data. I assumed that we would need $\overline{X}$; which I found to be $1.312670963$. In a past assignment we showed that as
\begin{equation}
n\rightarrow \infty, \tilde{\theta} = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2}\xrightarrow{d}N\bigg(\theta,\dfrac{\theta^2}{4n}\bigg)
\end{equation}
We are asked to construct an approximate $95\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$. If I have the Fisher function as $J(\theta)=\dfrac{4n}{\theta^2}$. Can I state
\begin{equation}
\bigg(\hat{\theta}-\dfrac{1.96\hat{\theta}}{2\sqrt{n}},\hat{\theta}-\dfrac{1.96\hat{\theta}}{2\sqrt{n}}\bigg)
\end{equation} 
Using the score function and setting it to $0$. I found:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\theta}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2}
\end{equation}

Would I be correct in using this in the above equation?
I am not sure how to start this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How does the Rayleigh distribution enter into this problem?

Comment: Only in the sense that it was the distribution that we started from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CI is "approximate", then assuming your $n$ is sufficiently large, you can use the asymptotic distribution of $\tilde\theta$. ie, for 95% confidence,

$$CI = \hat{\tilde{\theta}} \pm 1.96\times\sqrt\frac{\tilde{\hat{\theta}}^2}{4n}$$

Comment: How do I find $\theta$?

Comment: So, is $\hat{\theta}=\overline{X}$? Or do I use the score equation and set $S(\theta)=0$ as I did above?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  $\hat\theta$ will be the empirical version of your $\tilde\theta$.  ie,
$$\hat\theta = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\sum x^2_i}$$.